# Unable to create a list function--Python

Tags: python

Write a function, top_three, that takes a list as its argument, and returns a list of the three largest elements. For example, `top_three([2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1]) == [8, 6, 5]`. My attempt:

```
def top_three(input_list):

sorted_list= sorted([input_list], reverse=True)

top_three = sorted_list[ :2]

return top_three
```

Comment: `input_list` is already a list, you don't need to put it in brackets.

Comment: You need to indent the function body.

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't wrap your input in another layer of `list`.

```
sorted_list= sorted([input_list], reverse=True)
```

should be:

```
sorted_list = sorted(input_list, reverse=True)
```

or it's just sorting a one-item `list` (containing the whole of the `list` provided).

Side-note: For real world code, just [use `heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), which scales to large inputs and small numbers of items to select better than a global sort and slice:

```
import heapq

def top_three(input_list):
    return heapq.nlargest(3, input_list)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my stupidity. Am  a beginner here. Thanks a ton. Greatly appreciate. Cheers

Comment: Not stupidity, merely ignorance -- and we all start there.